Laravel validation: ignoring certain fields during update
How can I prevent Laravel from validating certain columns when editing an existing user? I'm trying to update a guest's information, but I want to ignore the phone and email fields if no changes have been made to the guest's details. However, when creating a new guest, it should properly check for uniqueness. How can I achieve this? I've been struggling with this issue for a while.
Here are my form validation rules:
return [
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'last_name' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
    'other_names' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
    'city' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
    'country' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
    'email' => ['required_if:phone,null', Rule::unique('guests')->whereNot('email',null)->where('hotel_id',auth()->user()->hotel_id) ],
    'phone' => ['required_if:email,null', Rule::unique('guests')->where('phone','!=', $request->phone)->where('hotel_id',auth()->user()->hotel_id) ],
    'address' => 'nullable|string|max:255', 
    'other_phone' => 'nullable|numeric:11',    
];

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe “sometimes” rule will help.

Just compare the value to save with the value in the model attribute. E.g.:
$guest = Guest::firstOrNew(/* ... */);
$new = !$guest->exists;

return [
    ...
    'email' => $new || $guest->email !== $request->email ? [/* validation rules */] : [],
    ...
];

